# How to open Mozilla Developer Edition from terminal

Tags: mac, firefox, terminal, terminal.app

I wish to open Mozilla Firefox Edition app with `index.html` from terminal in my mac but don't know the command. `firefox index.html` command doesn't work.

Comment: Where is `index.html` located? Try using the full path ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X, you will need to point it to the relative application. For Firefox, you will want to first CD in to the Firefox.app like `cd /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS`, in order to get to the folder with the actual application, and then run `./firefox index.html`.

Since the `index.html` file is likely in a different folder, you will want to CD in, then run `./firefox "pathway/to/file/index.html` (Inserting the correct path there.

Mozilla provides support for all their command line options, examples and usage [can be found here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-url_URL)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the **-a** switch.

open -a "Firefox" index.html

To avoid needing to remember the details, I have aliased this to

**alias open_firefox='open -a "Firefox"'**

which would give:

**open_firefox index.html**

OS X will figure out the Firefox app path from the contents of -a, which basically need to match what you see in the /Applications folder.

other examples to make that clearer:

open -a "Google Chrome"
open -a "Affinity Designer"
open -a "Sublime Text 2"
open -a "Affinity Photo"

caveat:  if your FF Dev edition is not found in the usual Applications directory or there is a name clash between regular FF and this FF, then you will need to use something else.

Comment: For Firefox Developer Edition: `open -a "FirefoxDeveloperEdition"`